# Logback error when migrating a PDF2 plugin from DITA-OT 4.0.1 to 4.1.2

Tags: logback, dita, dita-ot, logback-classic

I'm using oXygen XML with the DITA-OT and a custom plugin based on PDF2 to generate PDFs. I'm looking at upgrading the DITA-OT version from 4.0.1 to 4.1.2.
The change in the DITA-OT which generated the error seems related to the move from log4j to Logback, but beyond that, knowing very little about Java, I don't know how to investigate.

When attempting to generate a PDF, here's the error I get:

> Description: Transformation failed. C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.1.2\plugins\org.dita.base\build_preprocess2.xml:89: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class ro.sync.util.LogbackDefaultConfigurator does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method
> 'abstract ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator$ExecutionStatus configure(ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext)' of interface ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator.

Here are the libraries used with dita-ot 4.0.1 :
"C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.0.1\lib\logback-classic-1.2.8.jar" -lib "C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.0.1\lib\logback-core-1.2.8.jar" -lib "C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.0.1\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar"

Here are the libraries used with dita-ot 4.1.2 :
"C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.1.2\lib\logback-classic-1.4.8.jar" -lib "C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.1.2\lib\logback-core-1.4.8.jar" -lib "C:\Apps\DITA-OT\dita-ot-4.1.2\lib\slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar"

Do you know if I need to configure something in the DITA-OT, or if I need to check specific areas of the custom plugin? Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you tell me what Oxygen version you are using? Are you publishing from inside Oxygen or from a command line? If you are publishing from Oxygen after the publishing fails there should be a "DITA OT" console output tab containing lots of console logging which I might find useful to debug the problem. If you cannot share the entire console log here maybe you can contact us (the Oxygen XML team) directly through our support email address and send us the console log.

Comment: Thank you Radu, I've sent a message through OXML customer support with the relevant details.

Comment: Thanks for this, once we find a solution for this via email maybe we can post it also here for others who might encounter the same problem.

Comment: Solved within oXygen XML after checking the "prefer using the dita command" in the 'Advanced' tab of the "Edit scenario" window. Thank you for the very quick solve Radu!

Answer (score 1):

Updating with the solution which seems to have worked to fix this problem:

If you edit the transformation scenario you are using for publishing in Oxygen, in the "Advanced" tab there should be a checkbox named "Prefer using the "dita" command". You can check that checkbox, save the scenario and try to publish again.